# Microtik RB952Ui-5ac2nD stopped working after reset

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a Microtik RB952Ui-5ac2nD that after doing a reset (pressing the back reset button while plugging it to the power outlet) stopped working.

The router will boot normally, the lights will turn on, but no wireless signal will be  "thrown". I can verify this with  any of my two laptops, smart tv, phone and none detect any signal from the router.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Connect via cable. Do you get an IP address? Can you configure the device now?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you mean via usb cable or ethernet cable?

Comment: In general I would choose ethernet.

Comment: Connected to it via ethernet, doesn't work, not getting an ip address from it

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Connect to router via USB cable.
2. Set the wired network connection IP to 192.168.88.***(make sure *** is not 1) and the mask to 255.255.255.0.
3. Then open the browser and go to **http://192.168.88.1**, after connecting to the router, log in to the management page of the router.
4. Check if the wireless is turned on, if it is turned on, there is still no wireless signal, try resetting the router again.
5. If it is invalid after resetting again. It is recommended to contact the after-sales department to check if there is any problem with the router itself.